# Match all IP addresses in text with regex

Tags: ruby, regex, ipv4

Let's say I have string which might contain one or more IP addresses. How to match all of them and only valid ones using regex in ruby?

Currently, my solution looks like this:

```
IP_ADDR_REGEX = %r{
  \b
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
  \b
}x
```

This works well when IPs are separated with spaces e.g it extracts `192.168.1.1` from the text `bla bla 192.168.1.1 bla`. However it still extracts `192.168.1.1` in this case: `bla bla 192.168.1.1.1.1 bla`.

How to make it not match such cases? i.e when it is `192.168.1.1.1.1` my regex should not return a match. I've looked for many solutions about this problem but could not find what I want. I also tried to figure out the solution myself by matching only whitespaces in the end (because `\b` matches a `.` character as well) but I could not make it work.
Thanks

Comment: Just IPv4 addresses?

Comment: Please note that `[a:b:c::d:e:f]` is also a valid IP address, for example, as is `[::]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may solve it by adding lookarounds that will fail the match if the IP-like string is preceded with a digit and a dot or is followed with a dot and a digit:

```
IP_ADDR_REGEX = %r{
  \b                                        # Word boundary
  (?<!\d\.)                                 # Negative lookbehind: no "X." before
  (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
  \b                                        # Word boundary
  (?!\.\d)                                  # Negative lookahead: no ".X" after
}x
```

## [Regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/1fN3MG/3)

Note that in case you only want to limit matches to whitespace-separated substrings use

```
IP_ADDR_REGEX = %r{
  (?<!\S)                                    # Position not preceded with non-whitespace char
  (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
  (?!\S)                                    # Position not followed with non-whitespace char
}x
```

## [Regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/1fN3MG/4)

Note that `(?:...)` non-capturing group will enable easier usage with `String#scan` method to collect all matches from strings.

Answer (score 5):

You should change the word boundary matcher `\b` to an explicit space (and match it with positive lookaheads since you don’t want it to be returned):

```
IP_ADDR_REGEX = %r{
  (?<=\s|^)
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
  (?=\s|$)
}x

main ▶ 'bla bla 192.168.1.1.1.1 bla'[IP_ADDR_REGEX]
#⇒ nil
main ▶ 'bla bla 192.168.1.1.1 bla'[IP_ADDR_REGEX]
#⇒ nil
main ▶ 'bla bla 192.168.1.1 bla'[IP_ADDR_REGEX]
#⇒ "192.168.1.1"
```